# apacheでのSSL（SNI）設定について

Tags: apache, ssl

SNIにてSSLを使用する際に、ホスト名無し「hogehoge.com」の証明書は使用できますか？
現在、2ドメイン登録しています。
1.「domain1.com」
2.「www.domain2.com」
この時、「www.domain2.com」は、正常に認識しますが、「domain1.com」は、先に読み込まれた証明書を認識してしまいエラーとなります。
環境は、
httpd-2.2.15-39
openssl-1.0.1e-30
mod_ssl-2.2.15-39
です。
OSはcentos6.6

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex default
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin

NameVirtualHost *:443
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain1.com:443
    DocumentRoot "/home/data/domain1.com/public_html"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile /home/config/ssl_key/domain1.com/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/config/ssl_key/domain1.com/server.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/config/ssl_key/domain1.com/ca-bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.domain2.com:443
    DocumentRoot "/home/data/domain2.com/public_html"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile /home/config/ssl_key/www.domain2.com/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/config/ssl_key/www.domain2.com/server.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/config/ssl_key/www.domain2.com/ca-bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

こちらの記事などが参考になるでしょうか。

https://blog.apar.jp/linux/378/
http://e-garakuta.net/techinfo/doku.php/linux/apache-sni

SNIはホスト名に対して制約は特にないようですが、使うときにいくつか留意点があるようです。

- OpenSSLではTLS拡張オプションを指定
- 上記のOpenSSLを使ってApache Httpdをビルド
- ブラウザがSNIに対応していないと利用できない

また、できればインストールしたOSやApache HTTPDの導入や、httpd.confや参照しているconfファイルが提示されていれば、より明確になるかも知れません。ご参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。

OSは、CentOS_6.6にて作成しています
opensslは、yumで入れました、TLS拡張オプションですが、
https://www.softel.co.jp/blogs/tech/archives/2428
より、「OpenSSL 0.9.8k以降はデフォルトで有効」と記載されていましたが、
インストールされているのが、openssl-1.0.1e-30なので、有効とみて良いのでしょうか？

ブラウザはＷｉｎ７上で、ＩＥ１１とＣｈｒｏｍｅ43.0.2357.81 mで試しました。

ssl.confｗは以下になっています。この際は、両方とも証明書が認識されますが、domain1.comとwww.domain2.comの<virtualhost>の順番を逆にすると、domain1.com表示の際に証明書は、www.domain2.comが選択されています。
何かお気づきな点があれば教えてください。

※文字数オーバーでssl.confは、次のコメントに入れます

Comment: LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex default
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin

NameVirtualHost *:443
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

Comment: <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain1.com:443
    DocumentRoot "/home/data/domain1.com/public_html"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile /home/config/ssl_key/domain1.com/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/config/ssl_key/domain1.com/server.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/config/ssl_key/domain1.com/ca-bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>

Comment: <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.domain2.com:443
    DocumentRoot "/home/data/domain2.com/public_html"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile /home/config/ssl_key/www.domain2.com/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/config/ssl_key/www.domain2.com/server.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/config/ssl_key/www.domain2.com/ca-bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>

Comment: すいません。うまく改行が出来ないので、ssl.confを最初の質問に追記しました。
「VirtualHost *:443」「/VirtualHost *:443」が消えてしまっていますが、ServerNameの上から、SSLCACertificateFileの下に入っています

Comment: 別々のホスト名を返しますので、同一の証明書を使ってはいけません。

Answer (score 0):

1つの証明書しか有効にならないのは、「NameVirtualHost *:443」が設定されていないのではないでしょうか。もしくは、ブラウザが対応していないか。

「NameVirtualHost *:443」が設定されていないと、"httpd -t" で以下のエラーが出ます。

```
[warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
```

Comment: (追記) RHEL 6 / CentOS 6 の httpd, openssl は SNI に対応しています。

Comment: ssl.conf 拝見しました。特に問題ないように思いますが、何でしょうね。
試しに、クライアントに openssl s_client を使った場合、CN= 箇所は正しいものが返るでしょうか？
「echo -en 'GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: domain1.com\n\n' | openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -servername domain1.com」
「echo -en 'GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: www.domain2.com\n\n' | openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -servername www.domain2.com」

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみました。　VirtualHostで「domain1.com」が先頭の時は、「domain1.com」「www.domain2.com」と正常にCNが出ましたが、VirtualHostで「www.domain2.com」を先頭にすると、「domain1.com」を指定した時、CNは「www.domain2.com」となっています。
証明書は、「domain1.com」がRapidSSL、「www.domain2.com」がジオトラストのQuickSSLPremiumです。
証明書取る時のCNをwww月にしてSANs付でwwwなし対応可能な証明書とかにしなければならいとか、証明書種類とかで何か制限ってあるのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
"-servername domain1.com" を指定したときに、どちらの VirtualHost にも該当せずに、デフォルトの(設定の最初の) VirtualHost になってしまっているように思います。
応答も www.domain2.com のコンテンツが返るのではないでしょうか。
実際の「ServerName domain1.com:443」箇所は正しいでしょうか？

Comment: ご返答後、遅くなってしまいました。
お恥ずかしながら、初歩的なミスでした。ご指摘いただきました「ServerName」ですが、コピペのミスで「ServerName domain1.com.net:443」となっていました。
修正した所、正常に認識を致しました。ありがとうございました。